# Regex split not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string, which is a line from a csv. This string contains many values, of which one is structured like this

> {X=4535.12, Y=4535.12}{X=12345, Y=12345}etc...

I am using Regex to split this string, but have not succeeded so far by using this pattern

```
/(({X=\d+\.\d+, Y=\d+\.\d+})|({X=\d+, Y=\d+})|({X=\d+\.\d+, Y=\d+})|({X=\d+, Y=\d+\.\d+}))+/g
```

I tested this on a website and it matched the exact string I wanted and no others in a large amount of data, but when I split using it the split only gives a single value (the entire string as one)

Is there a certain functionality of `Split` I am missing that causes it to behave differently to standard matching, or is my pattern just incorrect?

The line in C# reads like so

```
string[] tempLine = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(line, @"/(({X=\d+\.\d+, Y=\d+\.\d+})|({X=\d+, Y=\d+})|({X=\d+\.\d+, Y=\d+})|({X=\d+, Y=\d+\.\d+}))+/g");
```

Comment: do you want to split the coordinates each  x,y ?

Comment: what is the line of code in c# that you are executing the split on? It may have some funky syntax

Comment: @BadroNiaimi I want the entire thing split from the rest of the line, it contains commas which should be removed.

Comment: @Isaac Edited question to include

Comment: In case you want just to *extract* the values, why not *extract* them with simple `[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+` regular exp and then assign even values to x and odd to y?

Comment: won't splitting on `(?<=})(?={)` suffice if the structure is consistent?

Comment: I guess that you need some thing like much or replace not split!!!

Comment: In C# regex patterns, you do not need to use regex delimiters, no the `/g` modifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your regex is overly complicated, you can simplify it to:

```
({X=\d+(?:\.\d+)?, Y=\d+(?:\.\d+)?})
```

And here's the resulting C# code:

```
string s =  "{X=4535.12, Y=4535.12}{X=12345, Y=12345}";
string regex = @"({X=\d+(?:\.\d+)?, Y=\d+(?:\.\d+)?})";

var matches = Regex.Matches(s, regex);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(match.Value);
    // Or whatever you want to do with any couple {X=something, Y=something}
}
```

Comment: I'd use `@"{X=[\d.]+,\s+Y=[\d.]+}"` regex. The validity of the float values matched should not be an issue here.

Comment: This is not quite what I want, sorry if I didn't specify well enough, I want the entire set of data to be separated, so if the data was like

**hello,{X=4535.12, Y=4535.12}{X=12345, Y=12345},goodbye** - I would want an array with three elements [0] = "hello"  [1] = "{X=4535.12, Y=4535.12}{X=12345, Y=12345}"  [2] = "goodbye"

Comment: Thank you for your help, I managed to get this to work by changing this pattern a tiny bit, I added `+` to the end and then made that its own capturing group so it was all returned. I then made the inside group non-capturing to only get the data once - I ended up with this        `((?:{X=\d+(?:\.\d+)?, Y=\d+(?:\.\d+)?})+)`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using this Regex string

```
((?:{X=\d+(?:\.\d+)?, Y=\d+(?:\.\d+)?})+)
```

This is a slightly edited version of the answer @Thomas gave, and as such I will mark his as the answer because it aided me in finding the solution and his answer is more general and more likely to help any others with this issue

Answer (score 0):

try

```
^(\s*\{\s*X\s*=\s*(\d*(\.\d*)?)\s*,\s*Y\s*=\s*(\d*(\.\d*)?)\s*\}\s*)*$
```

Comment: There is not that much whitespace in there, it is un-necessary in 90% of those places, could probably simplify down to ^({X=(\d+(\.\d+)?),\s*Y=(\d+(\.\d+)?)})$ - this also matches much much more than just the specified data

Comment: what about numbers in form .5 or 12.?